# String from Django template, but without returning a HTTPResponse

Tags: django, json, templates

I have a query set whose objects I'd like to use to populate a template. One view I have ends with

```
return render_to_response('entry.json', {'entry_list':r}, mimetype="application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

However I'd like to be able to serialise to json with a template like this without having to return a HTTPResponse. In pseudocode, this might be:

```
render('entry.json', {'entry_list':r}) #returns a string with the template entry.json
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django provides a built in shortcut for this.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut

I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish,  But you can just return JSON as your HTTPResponse. You can serialize objects to jason and return it without the use of any template.

Answer (score 5):

What @HankGay said is correct, though you sometimes might want to get the template response with out returning a HttpResponse, even though you are using Django correctly.

read this: [Rendering a context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context):

```
>>> from django.template import Context, Template
>>> t = Template("My name is {{ my_name }}.")

>>> c = Context({"my_name": "Adrian"})
>>> t.render(c)
"My name is Adrian."

>>> c = Context({"my_name": "Dolores"})
>>> t.render(c)
"My name is Dolores."
```

Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't handling HTTP requests, it doesn't make much sense to use Django, honestly. Look into [Jinja 2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) for a simple template engine that has lots in common w/ Django's, and [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) for an ORM that is equal or better than Django's.

Comment: I'm handling HttpRequests in Django, only I'm now playing with Piston too.

Comment: @SK9 if you're using Piston and just want to return an HTTP response w/ a JSON body, you should probably look into [`Emitters`](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#!emitters).

Comment: This in no way provides an answer to the question. He asked how to do it in Django, not whether django is the best choice.